# bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client

Tags: python, tensorflow, signature, serving

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/root/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py", line 56, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/root/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "/root/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py", line 51, in main
>       result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)  # 10 secs timeout
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 324, in **call**
>       self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 210, in _blocking_unary_unary
>       raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
>   grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, details="Default serving signature key not found.")

When I run the command:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client — server=localhost:9000 — image=./Xiang_Xiang_panda.jpg
```

I got the error:

> grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, details=”Default serving signature key not found.”)

The server is working well, but the problem happens.

Could you let me know what can I do to get rid of that?